# Using jquery ajax in Rails doesn't work properly.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

currently, I'm learning rails then I come up to the point to use jquery to send ajax for the form, I know about the ujs but I don't want to use it. I want to use the pure javascript or jquery for learning purpose ( understanding it ). So, I have this problem that ***when I click the submit the button it become disable*** and also when I use this way

```
$( function(  ) {
  var form = $( '#new_post' );
  var formData = $( form ).serialize();

  $( form ).submit( function( event ) {
    $.ajax( {
      type: 'POST',
      url: $( this ).attr( 'action' ),
      dataType: 'json',
      data: formData
    } ).done( function ( response ) {
      console.log( response );
    } )

    event.preventDefault();
  } )
} );
```

the serialize `formData` is empty but when I tried this way

```
$( function(  ) {
  var form = $( '#new_post' );    
  $( form ).submit( function( event ) {
    $.ajax( {
      type: 'POST',
      url: $( this ).attr( 'action' ),
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $( form ).serialize()
    } ).done( function ( response ) {
      console.log( response );
    } )

    event.preventDefault();
  } )
} );
```

which is I call directly the `$( form ).serialize()` inside the ajax. I don't understand what's the difference but I tried to do some research already and I can't find the answer.

By the way, this the rails form.

```
<%= form_for( post ) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
$( function(  ) {
  var form = $( '#new_post' );   
  // Directly use the variable created above
  form.submit( function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
      type: 'POST',
      url: form.attr( 'action' ),
      dataType: 'json',
      data: form.serialize()
    } ).done( function ( response ) {
      console.log( response );
    } )
  } )
} );
```

The below code will not work:

```
$( function(  ) {
  var form = $( '#new_post' );  
  //formData is empty when the page loads and the same value is getting assigned inside the ajax call which is wrong.
  //Therefore the best way is to directly get the data while submitting the form.
  var formData = form.serialize();

  form.submit( function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
      type: 'POST',
      url: form.attr( 'action' ),
      dataType: 'json',
       //Here formData is empty
      data: formData
    } ).done( function ( response ) {
      console.log( response );
    } )
  } )
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question is why the `formData` is empty if I declare above not directly inside the ajax and the button disabled after I click it? any idea about that?

Comment: As the form variable is already containing $('#new_post') which is a jQuery object, you should not again put a jQuery object in another jQuery selector. In the above code, you also try it like this: `var formData=form.serialize();` and then use formData inside the ajax call, it will work.

Comment: As for the disabled, please check the generated html, if there is any html attribute in the button tag, once the page is loaded which should be like `data-disable-with`.

Comment: I tried the second one but still it didn't work. The `formData` doesn't have any value.

Comment: Got it, formData value is empty when the page loads, it should be reinitialized on each submit click so that formData is captured. That's why one should do the query on submit only.

Comment: Yah! I found out it too. Ahahaha! btw, thank you with your reply. :D

Answer (score 0):

I know already why. lol

```
$( function(  ) {
  var form = $( '#new_post' );

  form.submit( function( event ) {
    var formData = form.serialize();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
      type: 'POST',
      url: form.attr( 'action' ),
      dataType: 'json',
      data: formData
    } ).done( function ( response ) {
      console.log( response );
    } )

  } )
} );
```

the `var formData = form.serialize();` should be inside the submit event, so that it have the data inputted by the user.